# Let m be an odd integer. Since gcd(2,m) = 1,2 is invertible modulo m. What is the inverse of 2 modulo m?

Tags: number-theory

Let m be an odd integer. Since gcd(2,m) = 1,2 is invertible modulo m. What is the inverse of 2 modulo m? Justify your answer.

I know that m being odd has a crucial part in this solution and what does the notation 1,2 is invertible modulo m mean?

Comment: That is a comma, not any special notation.  Read  it as: "Because $\gcd(2, m) = 1$, we know that $2$ is invertible $\mod m$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m$ is odd, $m + 1$ is even, so we see that

$$2 \cdot \frac{m + 1}{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$

Comment: why did you multiply by 2 and then divide by 2?

Comment: @Miller.Steve I've constructed a number that, upon multiplication by $2$, gives $1$.

Comment: You answer is as confusing to me as the question itself

Comment: @Miller.Steve An inverse of $2$ is a number $a$ such that $2a \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, by definition. I chose $a = (m + 1)/2$ because that happens to work.

Comment: so the inverse of 2 mod m is 2*(m+1)/2 congruent to 1(modm)?

Comment: @Miller.Steve The inverse of $2$ modulo $m$ is $(m + 1)/2$. The inverse should be a number, not an equation.

Comment: so it's 1/2? Is that correct?